# Too many inode?

Tags: osx, inode

I am using a MacBook Pro, and I found something weird recently, which is the number of ifree is ridiculously large. The following is the output of the `df` command:

```
$ df -i -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   234Gi  204Gi   19Gi    92% 2915232 9223372036851860575    0%   /
devfs          188Ki  188Ki    0Bi   100%     650                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4   234Gi   10Gi   19Gi    36%      10 9223372036854775797    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /home
```

As you can see, the number of my free inode is 9223372036851860575, and %iused is almost not able to be larger than 0%.

Is this normal? How should I do with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple filesystems don't use inodes in the way that Unix and Linux filesystems do.  The output of `df -i` is kinda a kludge to keep things working.

If you look carefully, the value you see is 2^63-inodes_used-1

What you're seeing is perfectly normal and not a problem.